# Debian, two IPv6 addresses on single interface

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6, interface

I need to add the second IPv6 to the single interface in Debian Stretch.
When using IPv4, this is simple becasue multiple `inet static` definitions works, i. e.:

```
iface enp5s0f0.10 inet static                                                   
  address 10.0.0.1                                                              
  netmask 20                                                                    

iface enp5s0f0.10 inet static                                                   
  address 10.0.0.2                                                              
  netmask 32
```

I get two addresses on the single interface.

But with IPv6 this does not work.

```
iface enp5s0f0.10 inet6 static                                                  
  address 9999:9999:9999:1::1                                                    
  netmask 64                                                                    

iface enp5s0f0.10 inet6 static                                                    
  address 9999:9999:9999:1::2                                                    
  netmask 128
```

Does someone know why this is not working? 
I think I can add a second address with `up -6 ip addr ...` in the interface configuration, but I would like to know why this works that way.

Comment: Can you show us the configuration file you're using? It's hard to troubleshoot with only the output, not the input. I assume you're using configuration files in "/etc/network/interfaces", as described in https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration and https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html

Comment: Hello, this basically the complete file from `interfaces.d`, one don't need more. I read the `interfaces` and Debian IPv6 page, but there are no info about multiple IPv6 addresses on a single interface.